# Amazon redshift get numbers after string regex

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

From a public example we got this:

```
select email, regexp_replace( email, '@.*\\.(org|gov|com)$') 
from users limit 5; 

              email                | regexp_replace 
-----------------------------------+----------------  
  DonecFri@semperpretiumneque.com  | DonecFri
  mk1wait@UniOfTech.org            | mk1wait
  sed@redshiftemails.com           | sed
  bunyung@integermath.gov          | bunyung
```

In my case I have strings such as this one:

```
ABCD01E002C
ABCSDD01E12C
```

And I want to retrieve the numbers between 1 and 9 after the `E` character
So the output would be `2` and `12` respectively for the above example

Comment: Try `REGEXP_SUBSTR(email, 'E0*([1-9][0-9]*)', 1, 1, 'e')`

Comment: @MiguelSantos wiktor has updated his comment, i think you try the latest it will work

Comment: It does work, can you formulate a formal answer maybe so I can mark it as correct? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Well, https://regex101.com/r/525m5D/1 shows it should work on `ABCD01E002C`

Comment: Miguel you have accepted the answer but then are you saying it doesn't work yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) to match `E` and any zeros after it, and then *capture* a digit from `1` to `9` and any digits after it into a capturing group:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(email, 'E0*([1-9][0-9]*)', 1, 1, 'e')
```

The `e` argument tells `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to return the first captured value.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/525m5D/1)

**Pattern details**

- `E` - a letter `E`
- `0*` - zero or more `0` chars
- `([1-9][0-9]*)` - capturing group #1:

  - `[1-9]` - a non-zero digit
  - `[0-9]*` - any 0 or more digits

Comment: can you explain me if I remove the 0 after the E why does it return me 1 for this example: ABCD01E002C instead of 2

Comment: @MiguelSantos No way, it is impossible as `E` can't match `D`

Comment: REGEXP_SUBSTR(email, 'E\*([1-9][0-9]*)', 1, 1, 'e') This exprection for this example ABCD01E002C returns 1

Comment: @MiguelSantos That should not be the case.

Comment: @MiguelSantos I have, and there is no `1` in the captured data anywhere.